# How to sent a sychronize a script over photon unity network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have a multiplayer game which uses a flashlight, and if I press `L` the flashlight turns off on the other game as well, but when `batteryTimeLeft` reaches 20 it only flickers on the local game.

How do I sync this whole script with all the users so that the flickering also goes over the network?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LightManager : Photon.MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject flashlight;
    public Light lightinflashlight;
    public bool Lightenabled = true;
    public float batteryTimeLeft = 100f;
    public float batteryDrainRate;
    public float minIntensity = 0.25f;
    public float maxIntensity = 8f;
    public bool flashlightRanOut = false;
    float random;
    float noise;
    public float time=3;
    void start(){
        PhotonView photonView = this.photonView;
        lightinflashlight = GetComponentInChildren<Light> ();
    }
    void Update () {
        photonView.RPC("publicUpdate", PhotonTargets.All); 
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {

        photonView.RPC("publicFixedUpdate", PhotonTargets.All); 

    }
    [PunRPC]
    public void publicFixedUpdate(){
        batteryTimeLeft -= batteryDrainRate;
        if (time < 0) {
            time = 0;
        } 
        time--;
    }
    [PunRPC]
    public void publicUpdate(){
        if (batteryTimeLeft >= 20) {
            flashlight.GetComponent<Light> ().intensity = 8;
            flashlightRanOut = false;
        }
        if (batteryTimeLeft < 0) {
            batteryTimeLeft = 0;
            flashlightRanOut=true;
        }
        if (!flashlightRanOut) {
            if (batteryTimeLeft <= 20) {
                if (time > 1) {
                    random = Random.Range (0.0f, 150.0f);
                    noise = Mathf.PerlinNoise (random, Time.time);
                    flashlight.GetComponent<Light> ().intensity = Mathf.Lerp (minIntensity, maxIntensity, noise);

                }
            }
            if (time < 0) {
                time = 3;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.L)) {
                Lightenabled = ! Lightenabled;
            }
            flashlight.SetActive (Lightenabled);
        } else {
            flashlight.SetActive (false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most optimized networking solution is the one that syncs data good and has least amount of data transferred, just send over network if the flashlight is on or off, and create timers on both clients, so flashlightRanOut will be generated independently on both clients, noise will be generated too on both clients, flickering will differ a bit since it uses random values but there is no need to have flickering perfectly same (it's also impossible to do this because delay messes it up).

Comment: but how do i do that?